# Unnumbered List Bullet points not centered

Tags: html

Having a slight issue with centering on a webpage.  The bullet points on my  are aligned to the left, when I'd prefer them to be centered and right before the list items.

http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~todtm/Assignment1.htm

The code for the list is very basic boilerplate code:

```
<center>
    <ul>
         <li>CS 325: Analysis of Algorithms</li>
         <li>CS 361: Software Engineering I</li>
         <li>CS 372: Intro to Computer Networks</li>
    </ul>
</center>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The center tag is deprecated in HTML. Another possible way to do this (or something similar) would be to have this in a fixed-width div, with margin: 0 auto. Here's a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xFA3h/).

```
<body>
<div style="
margin: 0 auto;
width: 400px;
text-align: center;">
<h1>Marshall Todt</h1>
<br>
<br>

<table align="center" border="1">
    <tbody><tr><td colspan="2">My Favorite Courses and Instructors</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Course</td><td>Instructor</td></tr>
    <tr><td>CS 165</td><td>Joseph Jess</td></tr>
    <tr><td>CS 494</td><td>Justin Wolford</td></tr>
</tbody></table>

<ul style="list-style-position: inside">
    <li>CS 325: Analysis of Algorithms</li>
    <li>CS 361: Software Engineering I</li>
    <li>CS 372: Intro to Computer Networks</li>
</ul>

<form method="post" action="submit.php">
<p class="legend">Rate a Class</p>
<fieldset id="Rating">
<label>Course:</label><input type="text" name="class" size="30"><br>
<p id="rating"><label>Rating: </label><select name="rating">
    <option value="5">5 (highest)</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="1">1 (lowest)</option>
</select></p>
<p id="buttons"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Took some playing with the width to get it to look nice, but that combined with adding some align="center" to a couple elements made everything good.

Comment: align="center" is also deprecated. What you really should be doing is assigning classes and/or ids to your divs (or ps or lis or what have your), and then making CSS rules for those classes and ids. I inlined the CSS, but ideally that would usually be in a separate file. It seems like you're working with some old tutorials or references, and you should look into finding some more up to date information.

Comment: Unfortuantely, for the class I am taking, they are teaching us in old tutorials.  The book we are using was written before chrome came out and is very big on XHTML.